# Win8 app crash on Win10 (D3D11CreateDevice return null)

Tags: c++, directx, windows-8.1, windows-10, toolkit

I have a Xamarin Forms-app writen in C# and using DirectX Tool Kit with interop calls to C++.

The app is an Windows 8.1 app and run great on Windows 8.1 and has runed on my Windows 10 computer.

But one day I started Visual Studio 2015 and was going to run the app on Windows 10. It just crash from no where. I think Windows 10 update can be the problem?

Anyway, here is some code from DirectX Tool Kit for Windows8.1:

```
ThrowIfFailed(
    D3D11CreateDevice(
    nullptr,                    // Specify null to use the default adapter.
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    0,
    creationFlags,              // Optionally set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags.
    featureLevels,              // List of feature levels this app can support.
    ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,          // Always set this to D3D11_SDK_VERSION for Windows Store apps.
    &device,                    // Returns the Direct3D device created.
    NULL,                       // Returns feature level of device created.
    &context                    // Returns the device immediate context.
    )
    );

// Get D3D11.1 device
ThrowIfFailed(
    device.As(&m_d3dDevice)
    );
```

D3D11CreateDevice seems to return null (device and context) 
 And crash in device.As(&m_d3dDevice) and the error message says that some SDK Component may be missing.

Anyone who know what the problem can be? Is there any DirectX SDK i must install? Why could I run the app Before?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide exact error message(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DirectX TK:
http://directxtk.codeplex.com/workitem/1317

> This is because your creationFlags are D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG which will fail if you do not have the Direct3D debug device installed--it's only on developer machines.
>
> Since you are on Windows 10, likely you were upgraded from one build to another which disables the debug device because it's outdated. You need to re-enable it.